# How to hide a div with asp:ListView

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a < div> with < asp:ListView>- with results of searching. I want to hide this div, and show it when ListView will be full (or better - when this part of code will be completed)

```
    lvSearchResult.DataSource = getSearchResult();
    lvSearchResult.DataBind();
```

How can I do this? Meanwhile when this < div> with listview will be not visible, I want to show another div with information "Loading". When ListView will be ready, < div> with results will show up, and < div> with "loading" will be hidden.

Comment: how big is the listview going to be that you want to hide it while loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an Update panel you can acheive with code similar to below. This will show a modal panel over the page while it is updating.

You could modify the start and end request methods to also hide / show the div containing the list view

note this uses jQuery.

```
    <div id="workingDialog" style="display: none" title="Please wait">
        <p>
           Loading Data
        </p>   
     </div>

<div id="listViewDiv" style="display:none">
//List View
</div>

<script>

var _workingDialog;


    //Page Load event
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        //Register events
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequest);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequest);

        _workingDialog = $('#workingDialog');
    }

    function beginRequest(sender, args) {
        $(_workingDialog).dialog({ modal: true });
        $('#listViewdiv').hide();
    }

    function endRequest(sender, args) {
        $(_workingDialog).dialog('close');
        $('#listViewdiv').show();
    }

</script>
```

http://wraithnath.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/showing-modal-dialog-while-page-is.html

Answer (score 1):

Declare your divs like:

```
<div id="searchResultDiv" runat="server" visible="false">...</div>

<div id="loadingDiv" runat="server">...</div>
```

The `runat="server"` makes them accessible in your asp.net code behind.

Then in your code you can change their properties, in this instance change the `Visibility`:

```
lvSearchResult.DataSource = getSearchResult();
lvSearchResult.DataBind();
searchResultDiv.Visible = true;
loadingDiv.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `runat="server"` attribute in your div

Then depending on any condition you can show or hide div

```
<div runat="server" id="myDiv">


var result = getSearchResult();    

    if(result!= null){
        myDiv.Visible = true;
        lvSearchResult.DataSource = result;
        lvSearchResult.DataBind();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on your list you can make a method that ads 2 css classes, one for when the list is full and one for the other case. so in one css you will have display: none; and in the other display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you could use css? and set display:none and when your condition is met change display to block/show?

Hope this helps: http://webdesign.about.com/od/dhtml/a/aa101507.htm

Answer (score 0):

add runat="server" to the div, then you can set visible = false/true

Answer (score -1):

Use AJAX with UpdatePanel , no? that will work..